# WCF Webservice Connection issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, wcf-binding, epicorerp

Let me start by saying that this is my first time working with WCF web services and I've been battling error for the last 3 days. These issues have been answered many times at Stackoverflow, however, I've tried most solutions and haven't been successful yet, so I need some help in figuring out the right way.

Now some background. I'm creating an ASP.Net MVC 5 project, I've to connect to WCF web services provided by Epicor (an ERP solution). My project, the ERP and its web services are all hosted on an internal IIS instance. The services are exposed using both BasicHTTP and NetTCP protocols. The application pool on which the web service and ERP are hosted uses identity.
One of the web service is called Company.svc and it is exposed as:

```
<wsdl:service name="CompanySvcFacade">
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_CompanySvcContract" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_CompanySvcContract">
        <soap:address location="http://pilotserver/ERP100700/Ice/BO/Company.svc"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="CustomBinding_CompanySvcContract" binding="tns:CustomBinding_CompanySvcContract">
        <soap12:address location="net.tcp://pilotserver/ERP100700/Ice/BO/Company.svc"/>
        <wsa10:EndpointReference>
            <wsa10:Address>net.tcp://pilotserver/ERP100700/Ice/BO/Company.svc</wsa10:Address>
            <Identity xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/02/addressingidentity">
                <Upn>pilotserver\Administrator</Upn>
            </Identity>
        </wsa10:EndpointReference>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

In my project, my web.config has the following:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_CompanySvcContract" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="CustomBinding_CompanySvcContract">
      <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"
        requireDerivedKeys="true" includeTimestamp="true" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
        <localClientSettings detectReplays="false" />
        <localServiceSettings detectReplays="false" />
      </security>
      <textMessageEncoding />
      <windowsStreamSecurity />
      <tcpTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://pilotserver/ERP100700/Ice/BO/Company.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_CompanySvcContract"
    contract="CompanyService.CompanySvcContract" name="BasicHttpBinding_CompanySvcContract" />
  <endpoint address="net.tcp://pilotserver/ERP100700/Ice/BO/Company.svc"
    binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_CompanySvcContract"
    contract="CompanyService.CompanySvcContract" name="CustomBinding_CompanySvcContract">
    <identity>
      <userPrincipalName value="pilotserver\Administrator" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

And I'm trying to consume the web service in the client using the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using EpicorTestApp.CompanyService;
using NLog;
namespace EpicorTestApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        CompanySvcContractClient CompanyService = new CompanySvcContractClient("CustomBinding_CompanySvcContract");
        //CompanySvcContractClient CompanyService = new CompanySvcContractClient("BasicHttpBinding_CompanySvcContract");
        private Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
            bool morePages = false;

            CompanyService.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Administrator";
            CompanyService.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "myPassword";
            CompanyListTableset companyList = CompanyService.GetList("", 0, 0, out morePages);
            CompanyListTable companies = companyList.CompanyList;
            foreach (CompanyListRow companyListRow in companies)
            {
                logger.Info("Company: " + companyListRow.Company);
            }           
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

For the client binding, I've tried both BasicHttp and NetTCP (as CustomBinding), both resulting in some errors. When I create a BasicHttp binding, I use the following service reference configuration:

[image: BasicHttpBinding]

and upon running this configuration, I receive an error for "Access is denied. Exception Details: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException: Access is denied."

[image: BasicHttp Error]

And for nettcp binding, when I try to create a service reference, I receive an error with the message "The URI prefix is not recognized. Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: net.tcp://localhost/ERP100700/Ice/BO/Company.svc'. I've tried using both localhost and pilotserver in the url.

[image: NetTcp Error]

I've tried running the application both in debug mode (ISS-Express) and publishing it to IIS, but same result. What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: It might be tricky to generate the net.tcp client code and contracts like that. Since it is on your local PC, try copying the Interface Contract and its dependent Data Contracts to the client application and use the ChannelFactory to make a net.tcp proxy for you. As for the BasicHttp one, you would need to capture that request and see what kind of information is being passed to the service that is saying that you are not authorized. You can use Fiddler, WCF Tracing or even (and I highly recommend) Wireshark to do that.

Comment: Some of the stuff I've mentioned assumes that you know the basics, and I will not be explaining them, there are lots of google tutorials and documentation out there that will.

Comment: FYI, you cannot add a service reference using the `net.tcp` protocol, you do it via `http`. As long as the service config exposes the `net.tcp` endpoint properly, you should be able to use it based on the WSDL pulled from the `http`. No need to add the reference a second time for `net.tcp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why I was getting all these errors was that in Web.config for Epicor's web services (inside IIS), https scheme for BasicHTTP was disabled/ comment out. I had to add the following to make my application work.

```
  <remove scheme="https" />
  <add scheme="https" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttp"/>
```

This is the default behavior in Epicor.

Answer (score 0):

In the `HomeController`, it would seem that this

```
CompanyService.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Administrator";
CompanyService.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "myPassword";
```

Should be something like this

```
CompanyService.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Administrator";
CompanyService.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "myPassword
```

You are passing the UserName twice in the code as you present it.

Comment: I can't believe this typo. Thank you for spotting this. However, the error is still the same. Thanks once again for this though.

Comment: Do you still get the access denied error when using the HTTP (`BasicHttpBinding_CompanySvcContract`) client after sending the password properly?

Comment: Yes, same error. Probably the question to ask at this point is how to set the credentials in webconfig and/or client code properly? I've tried both 'CompanyService.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName/Password' and 'CompanyService.ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName/Passowrd' combinations. Also, in windows eventviewer I've noticed I'm getting a 'Service authorization failed' error with an empty client identity 'ClientIdentity: '.

Comment: Another thing to consider: `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`. Worth a search. Create a `GenericPrincipal`, fill it, add it to that property. (??)